# Is there a way to get a useEffect cleanup to run when a user closes the webpage?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

So for some reason, if I wanted to run a function to update a database when the user leaves a page, I can do that with a useEffect return/cleanup function.  But is there a way to do that if they close the page/browser?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
    };
  }, []);
```

I tried testing like so, but never seemed to work.  So I am wondering if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Doesn't closing the browser immediately stop JavaScript?

Comment: @darthzeran, [onBeforeUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) may be what you're looking for

Comment: @NicholasTower, how would I use onBeforeUnload in react?  I try to put them in a useEffect, but when I close the tab, none of my alerts or logs or open in new tabs fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get notified when the window is just about to close, use the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const onBeforeUnload = (e) => {
   // run your cleanup code here
  }
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeUnload);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeUnload);
  }
}, []);
```

You are limited in terms of what you can do during this event. If you want, you can prompt the user whether they really want to close the page, which you do like this:

```
const onBeforeUnload = (e) => {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault(); // If you prevent default behavior in Mozilla Firefox prompt will always be shown
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
}
```

This will display an alert-like message, which you cannot customize. Typically you should only do this if the user has done something where they would expect this kind of message. Ie, they've made changes, and those changes havn't been saved, and they'll be annoyed if they lose them. If you're just running cleanup code, you probably don't need to do this.

You cannot redirect them to another page or show a custom alert. Malicious pages would love this: "Ha ha, you tried to leave my page, well i'm routing you back to it instead".

Comment: so I put a console log, alert, and a window.open inside the onBeforeLoad, but if I close the tab or click a link that takes me to a different website, nothing happens.

Is there some other step that I am just naively missing?

Comment: If you want to interrupt the user (eg, because they have unsaved changes that they care about), you can show a confirmation prompt by adding `e.preventDefault()` and `e.returnValue = ""`. But you cannot do redirects or custom alerts. And your console.log isn't showing up because the page is now closed, so there's no console in which to view it.